# Sqlite3 Delete Query shows successful but does not delete row or affect database

Tags: html, sqlite, sql-delete

Good day, trying to improve my webs skill by building a small web-app that stores contact information. The delete function  that allows users to delete contacts of the app shows a success message however the index page does not show the changes in the database.

Checking on an external DBReader (DB Browser) shows no changes made to the database. Based off lurking questions here the return type of request.form.get('affected_field_here') (what i use to get the value of the contact id)  returns none. Likewise i tried with request.args / request.values both of which showed the same problem

so can another pair of eyes tell me where i goofed?

Below is the delete function

```
    @app.route('/delete', methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def delete():

    conn = sqlite3.connect('contacts.db')

    db = conn.cursor()

    #Get contact_id
    contact_id = request.args.get('contact_id')

    
    db.execute("DELETE FROM contacts WHERE id =?", (contact_id,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    flash('Contacts removed', 'success')
    return redirect('/')
```

index.html code here

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title%}Landing Page{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="jumbotron p-3">

                <h1>My Contacts <button type="button" class="btn btn-success float-right" data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target="#addcontact"> Add Contact</button></h1>

                        <!--------------------Add Contact Modal placed inside same holder as modalit's for-->
                <div id="addcontact" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h3 class="modal-title">Add Contact</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form action="/add" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input  autofocus class="form-control"  autocomplete="off" required type="text" name="fname"  placeholder="Enter first name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input  class="form-control" autocomplete="off" type="text" required name="lname"  placeholder="Enter Surname">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input  class="form-control" autocomplete="off" type="number" min="1"  required name="age" placeholder="Enter Age">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input  class="form-control" autocomplete="off" type="number"  name="contact" required placeholder="Enter Contact Number">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input  class="form-control" autocomplete="off" type="email"  name="email" placeholder="Enter Email address">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Contact</button>
                                    </div>

                                </form>

                            </div>
                            

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(category_filter=["error"]) %}
            {% if messages %}
                {% for  message in messages %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                    <strong>Message: </strong>{{message}}
                  </div>
                {% endfor %}
              {% endif %}
              {% endwith %}

              {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(category_filter=["success"]) %}
                {% if messages %}
                    {% for  message in messages %}
                    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
                        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                        <strong>Success: </strong>{{message}}
                      </div>
                    {% endfor %}
              {% endif %}
              {% endwith %}
              

            <table class="table table-hover">

                <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td>First Name</td>
                        <td>Surname</td>
                        <td>Age</td>
                        <td>Contact #</td>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td>Action</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for row in contacts %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{row['id']}}</td>
                        <td>{{row['fname']}}</td>
                        <td>{{row["lname"]}}</td>
                        <td>{{row['age']}}</td>
                        <td>{{row['number']}}</td>
                        <td>{{row['email']}}</td>
                      
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target="#editcontact{{row['id']}}">Edit</button>

                            <form style='display:inline;' action="/delete" method="POST">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger""
                                onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove contacts?')">Delete</button></form>
                            
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                 
                <div class="modal fade" id="editcontact{{row['id']}}" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Contact Information</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form action="/edit" method="POST" autocomplete="off">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input  autofocus class="form-control"  autocomplete="off" required type="hidden" name="contact_id" value="{{row['id']}}" >
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input  autofocus class="form-control"  autocomplete="off" required type="text" name="fname_edit" value="{{row['fname']}}" >
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input  class="form-control" autocomplete="off" type="text" required name="lname_edit" value="{{row["lname"]}}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input  class="form-control" autocomplete="off" type="number" min="1"  required name="age_edit" value="{{row['age']}}" >
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input  class="form-control" autocomplete="off" type="number"  name="contact_edit" required value="{{row['number']}}" >
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input  class="form-control" autocomplete="off" type="email"  name="email_edit" value="{{row['email']}}">
                                </div>

                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Contact</button>
                                </div>

                            </form>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  {% endfor %}
                </table>

        </div>


    </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

the rest off appplication.py here incase it may be useful to:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect, app, url_for, get_flashed_messages
import sqlite3



app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "this_is_a_secret" #need a key to start app


@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('contacts.db')

    db = conn.cursor()

    contacts = db.execute("SELECT * FROM contacts")

    directory = [] #to store values

    for contact in contacts: #loop through query and append
        directory.append({
            "id": contact[0],
            "fname": contact[1],
            "lname": contact[2],
            "age": contact[3],
            "number": contact[4],
            "email": contact[5]})

    return render_template('index.html', contacts = directory) #load dic into html

@app.route('/add', methods=["POST"])
def add():

    conn = sqlite3.connect('contacts.db')

    db = conn.cursor()

    if request.method == "POST": #general back end error checking
            if not request.form.get('fname') or not request.form.get('lname'):
                flash('First name and Surname  are required fields.', 'error')
                return redirect('/')

            contact_age = request.form.get('age')
            if contact_age.isdigit() == False:
                flash ('Invalid age value', 'error')
                return redirect('/')
            
            contact_number = request.form.get('contact')
            if contact_number.isdigit() == False:
                flash ('Invalid contact number', 'error')
                return redirect('/')

            email = request.form.get('email')
            fname = request.form.get('fname')
            lname  =request.form.get('lname')

            db.execute("INSERT INTO contacts (fname, lname, age, number, email) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)", (fname, lname, contact_age, contact_number, email))
            conn.commit() 
            flash ('Updated your contact list', 'success')

            return redirect('/')

@app.route('/edit', methods=["POST"])
def edit():

    if request.method == "POST":

        conn = sqlite3.connect('contacts.db')

        db = conn.cursor()

        contact_id = request.form.get('contact_id')
        fname_n = request.form.get('fname_edit')
        lname_n = request.form.get('lname_edit')
        age_n = request.form.get('age_edit')
        num_n = request.form.get('contact_edit')
        email_n = request.form.get('email_edit')

        db.execute("""UPDATE contacts SET fname = ? ,lname = ?,age = ?,number = ?, email = ? WHERE id= ? 
        """,
        (fname_n,lname_n,age_n,num_n,email_n,contact_id ))
        conn.commit()
        flash('Contacts updated', 'success')
        return redirect('/')

@app.route('/delete', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def delete():

        conn = sqlite3.connect('contacts.db')

        db = conn.cursor()

        #Get contact_id
        contact_id = request.args.get('contact_id')

        
        db.execute("DELETE FROM contacts WHERE id =?", (contact_id,))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

        flash('Contacts removed', 'success')
        return redirect('/')
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

finally base.html which index.html reference

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %} </title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="jumbotron p-3">

        <div class="well text-center">
            
            <h1>PRACTICE WEB APPLICATION</h1>
    
        </div>
    
    </div>
    
    {% block body %}

    {% endblock %}
    

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

EDIT: Figured out answer. answer in post below.

Answer (score 0):

In delete function, i was referencing the wrong id, to solve thus i added a name attribute to the delete button  and reference that in the request.form function which allowed the function to work properly and reflect changes.

Hopefully this helps anyone stuck in a similar rut.